# DBeaver cannot import CSV with NULL in primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, import, dbeaver

I have a SQL table that I want to import data directly into via a CSV file. Because the table is live and being added to via API calls I do not want to specify the primary key (`APid`) in my import as I want it to auto-increment it as the import is processed.

Whenever I try to import the CSV I get the following error:

[image: Error message]

This is despite me both removing the column `APid` from the CSV, and also setting DBeaver to skip the column on import.

My import settings are as follows:

[image: Input file]

[image: Tables mapping]

[image: Data load settings]

The `APid` column is defined as follows:

[image: APid column]

Ideally I would like to avoid importing the data to a temp table and copying across, is there a way for DBeaver to skip this column and auto-increment it as it imports the CSV?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh sorry for the delay! It is running on Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: No problem. I added <sql-server> tag now.